# Why I cannot the get percentage by using Int

Tags: c#, integer-division

Please forgive my programming knowledge. I know this is a simple thing, but I do not understand why result is always 0. Why decimal will be fine?

```
int a = 100;
int b = 200;
decimal c = (a / b) * 100;
```

Many thanks.

Comment: That won't work. a * 100 / b still truncates the decimal and then converts to decimal type. You'd end up with no mantissa.

Comment: c = (a * 100M ) / b; Also, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Integer division always truncates the remainder. This is done at the time that the number is divided, *not* when it's assigned to the variable (as I'm guessing you assumed).

```
decimal c = ((decimal)a / b) * 100;
```

Comment: Truncation is also known as the mathematical Floor operation.

Comment: @rlb.usa: Whether it's a proper floor depends on how it handles negatives.  Off-hand, I believe it changes -1.2 to -1, not -2, though.

Comment: @rlb.usa: IEEE specs say that flooring rounds toward negative infinity. Fractional components of positive numbers are truncated, but any fraction of a negative number will cause it to round down (i.e. -1.1 becomes -2). Casting in this manner truncates the fractional component, so -1.1 would become -1.

Answer (score 14):

The value a/b will return 0 always since they are integers. So when the values within the Brackets are evaluated you are technically doing this

```
decimal c = (0) * 100
```

Better do,

```
decimal c = ((decimal)a/(decimal)b) * 100
```

Comment: -1 for confusing and misleading answer. `int/int=int`, which you seem to know but didn't explain.

Comment: "a/b will return 0 always" unless different values are given for `a` and `b`, in which case it will be `a / b`.

Answer (score 9):

100 / 200 is 1/2 or 0.5. Since you are using ints, it rounds down to 0 (zero). And 0 * 100 is still 0. The part inside the parentheses is always evaluated first: if you want to get this working, use:

```
decimal c = (a * 100) / b;
```

Edit: if you want a more precise value rather than an "integer percentage" (ie. 33.333% instead of 33%), you should use Bragaadeesh's answer.

Comment: As I said to Stu Mackellar, this doesn't quite work because it truncates.

Comment: If you rewrote that as `(a * 100M) / b`, you would get the result you desire.

Comment: @Steven, as I said to you in his answer, that may be what Daoming wants. It is how I interpreted his request, given he is starting with ints and wants a percentage. @Anthony likewise, I *want* an integer answer.

Comment: @tlofin, and as others have said, if he *wanted* an integer answer, he would store it as an *integer*.

Comment: @Anthony, who knows, you may be right. I think it's better to give both answers so he can choose which he wants.

Answer (score 2):

Integer math is being performed, and the result is *then* being stored as a decimal. 100 / 200 in integer math is 0. To get your percentage, cast at least one value to decimal before doing the calculation.

```
decimal c = (a / (decimal)b) * 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

The math being done is still integer math.

(a/b) (100/200 or 1/2) is done on two integers, so the result is zero.  Zero * 100 is ... well, still zero.

The problem you are experiencing is with the order of operations (a and b are integers, so integer math is performed).

I suggest this:

`decimal c=((decimal)a)/((decimal)b)*100;`

This will force the math performed to the decimal values you seek.

Comment: Use 100.0M instead of 100 to avoid cost of the implicit cast.

Comment: But then make sure you use 100.0M on the first op. (See other answers for clarification.)

Answer (score 1):

In strongly typed languages, the result of math operations is usually the same type as the larger type.

C# has a list of [implicit numeric conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx) it will do.

Generalizing this list:  Integral types can be converted to floating point types, but not vice versa.  Integral types can also be implicitly converted to `decimal`, but floating point types cannot.

Note: This also means that casting one of the ints to another type will result in the entire answer being that type.
ex: `(decimal) a / b * 100.0 = 50.0`

tl;dr:

In C#:

```
int / int = int
int + decimal = decimal
decimal + int = decimal
int / int * decimal = (int / int = int) * decimal = decimal
int - float = float
int * double = double
float / decimal = an error
int - uint = an error (either that or ulong)
```

Comment: `100 / 200 * 100.0` would still be 0 even though it yields a decimal result - mind it.

Comment: @sr pt: The fourth example down addresses that.  Specifically, with numbers substituted: `100 / 200 * 100.0 = (100 / 200 = 0) * 100.0 = 0.0`

Answer (score 0):

Make it `decimal c = (a * 100) / b;`

Comment: I do not think this will work as you imagine.  It will round down.  For example, if a=1 and b=3, we want c to be 33.333 (up to as many trailing 3's as we can hold).  With your code, we'd have 33.0

Comment: True. The OP didn't mention that he wanted a real number, but I guess it's implied by the decimal.

Comment: If you rewrote that as `(a * 100M) / b`, you would get the result you desire.

Comment: @Steven, we don't know which Daoming wanted. Given he's using ints, he may want the percentages rounded. @Stu, you've got an extra ending parenthesis there (edit:fixed).

Comment: @tloflin In that case it should be 'int c'.  Also, it should definitely be mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

int can only be whole numbers, so 100/200 is going to be 0.  0*100 is still 0. Change the type to a decimal, and it will work

Answer (score 0):

While using integers, this '/' stands for DIV and this '%' for MOD. DIV is the quotient of the division, MOD is the rest. So, 100/200 = 0 and 100%200 = 100.

So, you need to change `a` and `b` types to `decimal`, in your case.