# C# double, decimal problems

Tags: c#, integer-division

Why does this calcuation: double number = (13 /(13+12+13))

equals 0?

It should be around 0.34, I think!

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why I cannot the get percentage by using Int](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602025/why-i-cannot-the-get-percentage-by-using-int)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are dividing an `int` with an `int`. You should be doing

```
double number = (13.0 /(13.0+12.0+13.0));
```

Answer (score 1):

That are integers. So it does integer division. And thus truncates to the next lower(closer to 0) integer.

Add a `.0` to a number like `13.0` to make it a double.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using all `INT` in your formula - it will be treated as `INT` for the result too.

Try this instead:

```
var result = 13.0 / (13.0 + 12.0 + 13.0)
```

and your result will be:

```
0.34210526315789475
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a .0:

(13.0 /(13+12+13))

Otherwise you're dealing with integers.

Answer (score 0):

**Another option** is to cast *one* of the arguments explicitly to double and thus forcing the runtime to perform *double* division. e.g. :

```
double result = ((double)13 / (13 + 12 + 13));
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a ".0" will help:

```
double number = (13.0 /(13.0+12.0+13.0));
```