# Convert Rank to percentage C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to display percentage based on the rank of each record returned in search. I want it to loop through each item but it only loops through the first item as many times as I have items. For instance if it found 4 results it would display the rank of the first one on all 4 results.

Any suggestions to get it to display each rank separately and convert it to percentage?

```
private void BindRpt()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text)) return;
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB"].ConnectionString);
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.CommandText = "select Distinct Rank, SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 1, 500) AS ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE from FREETEXTTABLE (TABLE , ColumnA, '" + Search.Text + "'  ) S, TABLE C WHERE c.ID = S.[KEY] order by Rank Desc";

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    PagedDataSource pgitems = new PagedDataSource();
    pgitems.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
    pgitems.AllowPaging = true;

    pgitems.PageSize = 3;
    pgitems.CurrentPageIndex = PageNumber;
    if (pgitems.Count > 1)
    {                
        rptPaging.Visible = true;
        ArrayList pages = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i <= pgitems.PageCount - 1; i++)
        {
            pages.Add((i + 1).ToString());
        }
        rptPaging.DataSource = pages;
        rptPaging.DataBind();

        lblSentence.Visible = true;
        lblSearchWord.Visible = true;
        lblSearchWord.Text = txtSearch.Text;
    }
    else 
    {
        rptPaging.Visible = false;

        lblSentence.Visible = true;
        lblSentence.Text = "Results were found for";

        lblSearchWord.Visible = true;
        lblSearchWord.Text = txtSearch.Text;
    }
    rptResults.DataSource = pgitems;
    rptResults.DataBind();
    cn.Close();
}

protected void rptResults_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HTAA"].ConnectionString);
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = cn;
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    cmd.CommandText = "select Distinct Rank, SUBSTRING(ColumnA, 1, 500) AS ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE from FREETEXTTABLE (TABLE , ColumnA, '" + Search.Text + "'  ) S, TABLE C WHERE c.ID = S.[KEY] order by Rank Desc";


    int number = Page.Items.Count;
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if(dr.Read())
    {
        int firstrank = dr.GetInt32(0);
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            int rank = dr.GetInt32(0);
            int percentage = (rank / firstrank) * 100;
            Label lblpre = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRank");
            lblpre.Text = percentage.ToString();
        }
    }
    dr.Close();
    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: `int percentage = (rank / rank) * 100;` Will always result in a value of 100, no matter what `rank` is.

Comment: Your code has a number of issues.  In addition to the logic error pointed out above, and the looping issue pointed out in the answers, it's vulnerable to SQL injection.  You're not properly wrapping things in `using` statements.  You may want to do a bit more research on the basics.

Comment: What do you expect the data to look like? If you have four records, they're ranked 1..4, right? What should your result look like?

Comment: I changed the code, it seems like it is doing it but it displays 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a chat, I have a better handle on things. A way to do this;

Create a private field on your code behind file.

```
private int topRanked = 0;
```

In your Bind method()

```
private void Bind() 
 { 
 ... 
 DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
 adapter.SelectCommand = cmd; 
 adapter.Fill(dt); 

 topRanked = (int)dt.Rows[0]["Rank"];
```

Now, make your OnItemDataBound method;

```
protected void OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) 
 { 
 var dataItem = e.Item.DataItem as DataRowView; 
 int rank = (int) dataItem["Rank"]; 

 var percentage = ((double)topRanked / rank) * 100; 

 Label label = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("labelRank"); 

 label.Text = percentage.ToString(); 
 }
```

as mentioned. I don't believe it's the best answer, but it is an answer. I'm sure a stored procedure, or even a better sql method could probably calculate this and not leave you making calculations in code.

Comment: You're going to have to loop through the entire set anyway, but to calculate the rank, I'm thinking.

Comment: I'm trying, but again though, what are you expecting the data to look like? I'm certain that the label code in that loop is absolutely incorrect.

Comment: The data should like this 100, 95, 92 depends on the rank number

Comment: it looks like the it does not save the value of (x/y)*100. For some reason itt always either 100 or 0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602025/why-i-cannot-the-get-percentage-by-using-int

Comment: This works as far as the math but it sets all 4 items to show 74.223

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58515/discussion-between-hammerstein-and-vt146911).

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with while(dr.Read()) instead of "if"?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to loop over the result set

```
while (dr.Read())
{
   int rank = dr.GetInt32(0);
   int percentage = (rank / rank) * 100;
   Label lblpre = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblRank");
   lblpre.Text = rank.ToString();

}
```

Comment: `rank / rank` will always be `1`.

Comment: I didn't edit that part of his code, just copied it from the original. The point was to show how to iterate the result set.

Comment: hmm.. I see what you saying so how should I do it?

Comment: I need somehow to set the first result to an int and use it when dividing but how to do it?

Comment: To display each rank separately you will have to have multiple labels or concatenate the different ranks as a string.

Comment: I believe dr.GetInt32(0) will retrieve the value of the first column of your SQL result set as an integer, I am not sure how your dataset looks maybe having that info will help.

Comment: I am using a repeater control, I did not mention that.

Answer (score 0):

**"but it only loops through the first item"** - because you have a `for` and checks for `i <= 0`

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++) 
{
   ....
}
```

You just don't need this `for` statement but rather use

```
if (dr != null)
   using (dr)
   {
         while (dr.Read())
         {
          ..
         }
   }
```

It's always better to use `using` when dealing with db connection objects so the resources used by these objects are properly disposed after it's been used.

Comment: I deleted the for loop